# python __setattr__ attribute issue

Tags: python, setattr

I have a class designed to work with postgresql db:

```
dbclass = DBclass(1)
class DBclass(object):
    select_query    = 'SELECT * FROM "{table}" WHERE {table}_id=%s'

    def __init__(self, id=None):
            self.__id       = id
            self.__table    = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
```

And I have `__setattr__` overloaded:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    super(DBclass, self).__setattr__(name, value)
    self.load()
```

And method used to connect to load content from db:

```
def load(self):
    # Here I send select query and get two remaining values
```

With this `__setattr__` I only can initialize `__id` and `__table` values. There are still two fields which are in my database which are not loading. I can not initialize them using `__setattr__` because `__table` variable is not initialised yet as well as `__id` and python can not call load method and send query.

Perhaps I put wrong logic in my decision and values from db shouldn't be initiated like that.

Comment: Next time, include the error you're getting when you try to assign values. I suspect load() triggers a couple different errors depending on the conditions and it would be easier to be confident about responses when the errors are included. It also helps show that you've tried a couple things before asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that your `load()` method will assign your other two values which means it will be calling `__setattr__()` at least twice. Unless you have logic in `load()` to avoid it you almost certainly creating an infinite loop. A basic load method is not likely something you want to call from within `__setattr__()` as it would likely have unexpected side effects (for example any time you update any value on the object, all the values in the database would get reset).

Just move the `load()` into `__init__()` and get rid of `__setattr__()` entirely.

```
 def __init__(self, id=None):
    self.__id       = id
    self.__table    = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
    self.load()
```

Comment: Yeap, good advice. But is there any way in python to put load into setattr so first __table would be initiated and then load method called?

Comment: Sure: make the load call conditional on the existence of __table. That's still probably not a great idea; you'll need to do something to prevent load() from calling __setattr__(), which is also possible but ugly. You should make sure you have a really good reason to justify that design choice.